# If $\gcd(a,b)=1=\gcd(c,d)$, $b>0$, $d>0$ and $\frac {a}{b}+ \frac {c}{d}$ is an integer, show that $b=d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd(a,b)=1=\gcd(c,d)$, $b>0$, $d>0$ and $\frac {a}{b}+ \frac {c}{d}$ is an integer, show that $b=d$.

Can someone give me hints to solve the problem? I have a feeling that we need to show that $b|d$ and $d|b$, but cant figure out how to do it. Can anyone help me? Just need some hint not the entire solution!

Comment: What do you mean by $(a,b) = 1$? Can you explain the notation?

Comment: It means $gcd(a,b)=1$

Comment: thats the notation used in my book @gemspark

Comment: It would be better if you add this info in the question text, @Kritesh Dhakal.

Comment: It's obvious using uniqueness of reduced fractions - see my answer in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}\in\mathbb Z\implies b|(ad+bc)$$but $b|bc\implies b|ad$ and as $b$ and $a$ are co-prime, $b|ad\implies b|d$. Similarly, we get $d|b$ and thus, $b=d$.

Comment: Thanks it was simple and elegant as well!

Comment: @KriteshDhakal You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You have that $ad+bc$ is divisible by $bd$. Then $ad$ must be divisible by $b$. Since $(a,b)=1$ we have that $b$ divides $d$. Similarly $bc$ is divisible by $d$, so $d$ divides $b$. Hence $b=d$.

Comment: Thanks it was simple and elegant!